# Pipes with Apt Package Manager

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, apt-get

I have two files, the first one called `packages.txt` which is list of packages:

```
gcc
emacs
vim
python
...
```

Now, when I run the command

```
cat packages.txt | tr '\n' ' ' | apt-get install
```

This basically converts the file into one line of packages separated by space. It does not install all the packages in `packages.txt.` (I think it only installs the first one) Does anyone knows why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `xargs`:

```
xargs -d '\n' -- apt-get install < packages.txt
```

Or

```
xargs -d '\n' -n 1 -- apt-get install < packages.txt
```

Make sure `packages.txt` is not in DOS format:

```
sed -i 's|\r||' packages.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but why doesn't my method work?

Comment: @Husain I'm not sure as I don't use `apt-get` but my guess is that apt-get only processes one input per instance. Second is that some applications apt-get tries to summon may also be reading input and eats up the whole input from the file.

Comment: If you want it to accept skip the installation  « accept », use the apt -y parameter

Answer (score 1):

The pipe operator sends the `stdout` of one application into the next (as `stdin`. Unfortunately, `apt-get` does not read from `stdin`. Rather, `apt-get` takes a list of packages on the command line. I think what you are attempting to do is more along the lines of

```
apt-get install $(cat packages.txt | tr '\n' ' ')
```

or

```
apt-get install `cat packages.txt | tr '\n' ' '`
```

Which is to say evaluate the file list, and pass it in as an arguments to a single `apt-get` call.